# using powershell how we can read all filenames, lines count in each file and directory name in a folder for every day

Tags: powershell-3.0

I'm using the following script

```
$sourceTree = 'C:\MyFolder\test\error' 

Get-ChildItem $sourceTree -recurse -include @("*.CSV*") | 
Where-Object {$_.CreationTime} | 
Select-Object CreationTime, DirectoryName, Name, Lines | 
Export-Csv C:\test.csv
```

I'd like to read the line count for each file. 
How can I do it?